# why I cannot use strings in Column array with tooltips? Google charts

Tags: angular, angular-google-chart

I would like to know, why is it impossible to do something like this

```
this.columnNames: Column[] = ['name', 'value',  {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true}}]
```

I'm getting error:

```
Type '{ type: string; role: string; p: { html: true; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Column'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'p' does not exist in type 'ColumnSpec'.
```

that prevents code from compiling, but on the google docs they do it the same way...

This is the information from docs
"Mark an entire column, or a specific cell, in the data table with the html custom property. A datatable column with the tooltip role and HTML property would be:
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}})"
So it should works. The only difference is I'm using just Columns without DataTable

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in stackbiltz and share

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwvdv3?file=src/app/hello.component.ts I'm not sure why but on stackblitz it looks like it's ok, in Intelij I got mentiond error and when I compile my app in the internet browser I see the same error